# Como usar string em C++?

Tags: c++, string

Estou com problemas pra lidar com `string`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool ArqExiste(string Arquivo)
{
    ifstream verificacao (Arquivo.c_str());
    if(verificacao.is_open())
    {
        verificacao.close();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        verificacao.close();
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string file = "C:\\Temp\\aipflib.log";

    printf("%b", ArqExiste(file));
}
```

Na linha `ifstream verificacao (Arquivo.c_str())`, deu o erro:

> variable 'std::ifstream verificacao' has initializer but incomplete type

Eu uso o Codeblocks pra programar.

Comment: Não que seja o motivo do problema, mas tem alguma razão para usar o `c_str()`? Experimenta adicionar: `#include <fstream>`

Comment: Qual a versão do C++ que esta utilizando? (C++11 ou C++98) pois possuem construtores direfentes.

Comment: Não seria necessário um segundo parâmetro para este construtor? pois dependendo do seu objetivo será necessário passar um segundo parâmetro http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/

Comment: Resolveu o problema com a solução que te passei?

Comment: Sim, resolveu. Obrigado mesmo, fera.

Comment: Quanto á versão do C++, eu não faço ideia. Qual é o melhor programa pra C++. Codeblocks? Visual Studio?

Comment: @MarceloNascimento não existe o melhor programa, isto é gosto, cada um tem suas vantagens e desvantagens. De qualquer forma estes programas que você falou são apenas o IDE e não o compilador, apesar de que cada um deles vem com compiladores específicos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você não inclui o cabeçalho necessário no caso o `#include <fstream>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

bool ArqExiste(string Arquivo) {
    ifstream verificacao (Arquivo.c_str());
    if(verificacao.is_open()) {
        verificacao.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        verificacao.close();
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    string file = "C:\\Temp\\aipflib.log";
    printf("%b", ArqExiste(file));
}
```

Veja [funcionando (aproximadamente) no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/b9GgDZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nkrtdgtr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Library/FStream.cpp).

Também tirei o `conio` que por sorte não está sendo usado neste código. Esse cabeçalho nunca deveria ser usado em códigos modernos.

Considere também não usar o `c_str()` aí, ele não é necessário.

Comment: Valeu mesmo pela ajuda.