# Como fazer um excelente programa C++ sem rastros de C?

Tags: c, c++, característica-linguagem, estilo-de-codificação

Como iniciante em C++ fiz aqui algumas perguntas e fui advertido algumas vezes por @Maniero que o que eu estava fazendo era C e não C++. O problema é que C++ permite-nos usar muitas coisas semelhantes a C.

Pergunto então: como fazer um programa "verdadeiramente" C++ (sem usar hábitos do C)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Não é fácil fazer uma lista extensiva, vou tentar colocar o que é mais importante sem preocupação com pequenos detalhes (exemplo: não ter que usar [`void`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138582/101) para garantir que uma função não tem parâmetros).

Lembrando que não é que seja proibido usar, mas é bom se acostumar com as partes específicas do C++, que é inclusive uma linguagem em mutação, então a melhor forma de fazer varia de versão para versão (que está em cadência fixa de 3 anos) e não recomendo nem mesmo usar alguns recursos que existiam em C++ antes do padrão C++11.

Algumas coisas de C precisam ser usadas em código bem de baixo nível, quando fará algo mais concreto, a própria biblioteca padrão do C++ está cheio disto, mas está lá para você não ter que usar. Se estiver fazendo algo assim pode ser interessante ou obrigatório usar. Em alguns raros casos, a performance só poderá ser obtida fazendo no estilo C, a maioria é igual ou mais rápido fazer no estilo C++ (sim o C++ pode ser mais rápido que C em muitos casos).

Está em curso um plano de implementação para futuras versões (se não foi abortado) algo que impede usar os recursos problemáticos da linguagem, incluindo aí os originários de C, com possibilidade de liberar o acesso específico de cada *feature* em um trecho bem demarcado.

Algumas coisas que ainda se faz em C nem mesmo em C deveria fazer mais, por exemplo declarar variável no começo da função. Estou considerando que as pessoas já seguem o estilo de C99. E que saibam fazer bem, tem erros que vejo por aí que nem é de usar C em C++, é fazer mal uso até em C, só que em C++ o bom uso seria diferente.

C++ procura mais robustez e performance, então tem que entender cada mínimo detalhe da linguagem para entender isso. Essa são duas linguagens que você não pode se comprometer pela metade como dá em várias outras, no mínimo não vale a pena usá-las se não estiver 100% comprometido.

Antes de tudo o estilo de como escreve também muda, em geral em C++ procura mais a legibilidade, em C procura ser mais sucinto e menos digitação.

Algumas coisas aqui estou falando grosso modo.

- A primeira coisa que não deveria usar é a [biblioteca de C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199892/101). Nada deveria ser usado, e ter um `include` com `<algo.h>` ou `<cNomeDoC>` já indica que está fazendo errado. Se considerar isso já praticamente não consegue fazer quase mais nada em C, mas pode ainda ter um estilo C ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/353867/101)).
- Usar praticamente qualquer coisa que seja do pré-processador está errado, principalmente `#define` e [macros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75075/101) e em parte o `#ifdef` e outras diretivas. Tudo tem solução melhor em C++, como o uso de `const`, [`enum`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136467/101), [`constrexpr`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/331579/101), o [*inlining*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183990/101) de funções ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241534/101)) e *templates*. Somando isso já elimina muitos outros casos.
- Um dos pontos mais importantes é não usar ponteiro bruto e preferir [referências](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81611/101), [ponteiros inteligentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83886/101), além de não usar *array* bruto que decaem para ponteiros e preferir abstrações da biblioteca como [`array`, `vector`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163424/101), [`string`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73698/101), [`string_view`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324205/101), etc. Estes 3 pontos matam quase tudo que é mais importante para eliminar C do seu código.
- [Evite *casts* brutos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243864/101), tem alguns *templates* prontos que fazem isto melhor.
- Use [*lambdas*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/270895/101) e suas [variações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361612/101) no lugar de ponteiros para funções.
- Use a capacidade de *generics* dos [*templates*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57790/101) [no lugar de `void *`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/261616/101) ou outros truques ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97138/101)).
- Esquecer de usar [*namespaces*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/348049/101) é algo ruim (logo vem os módulos).
- Em geral declarar algo como [`static`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/259785/101) no sentido de tornar privado a um arquivo não é mais muito adequado. A palavra-chave ainda faz sentido para outro contexto.
- Preferir [*for range*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112029/101) com iteradores ou [algoritmos prontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/336202/101) do que `for` bruto.
- Funções possuem [*overload*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/360431/101), use-os.
- `struct`s e [`class`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/263534/101)es são bem mais poderosas, por exemplo pode ter privacidade nos membros, ou as funções podem pertencer a elas, até se tornando métodos.
- Códigos mais modernos estão [preferindo `using`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/342787/101) no lugar de `typedef`.
- C++ tem [`auto`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/371339/101), embora raramente necessário de fato é mais idiomático, já `decltype` tem situações mais úteis e necessárias, o que pode eliminar certos truques de PP.
- Alguns casos [o que colocar em um `.hpp` pode ser diferente do que colocaria em um `.h`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/226328/101) seu ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277171/101)).
- Vale lembrar que C++ é orientada a objeto, mais funcional, tem outras maneiras de produzir o mesmo resultado.
- E em C++ tem muita coisa pronta que C não tem, aprenda-as, tem um jeito novo, mais simples e robusto, quando não é mais performático também.

Essas coisas são um bom começo.

Também não é porque tem em C++ que é coisa boa pra usar. Existem casos que fazer mais estilo C++ pode complicar a interoperabilidade com C se for necessário, principalmente se C for o consumidor (isso é mais raro).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).