# Escrevendo em uma matriz C++

Tags: c++, matriz

Estou estudando e implementando uns esquemas em C++ porém está ocasionando erros na hora de atribuir valor para a matriz.
Bom... tenho um arquivo txt que contem linhas com o conteúdo "nome email@email.com".
Minha variável ret está retornando corretamente os valores, porém na hora de inserir no vetor estoura o seguinte erro:

> Exceção gerada em 0x0F6DE559 (ucrtbased.dll) em ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC0000005: violação de acesso ao gravar no local 0xCCCCCCCC.

Debugando o código, todos os valores estão aparentemente corretos, porém a exceção é lançada mesmo assim.
Anteriormente tentei fazer o mesmo processo sem o strcpy, inserindo diretamente no index desejado e utilizando strtok para separar a string, porém o valor de todos os index eram alterados para o último registro sempre.
Alguém poderia me dar uma luz para entender onde estou errando?

```
FILE *fp = NULL;

fp = fopen("Emails.txt", "rt");

char* matriz[99][2];

int index = 0;
char str[256];
char nome[20];
char email[60];

while (1)
{
    char *ret = fgets((char*)str, 255, fp);

    if (ret == NULL)
        break;

    sscanf(str, "%s %s", &nome, &email);

    strcpy(matriz[index][0], nome); // Acusa erro aqui!
    strcpy(matriz[index][1], email);

    index++;
};
```

Comment: Mas se é C++ porque fez um código em C? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/392951/101

Comment: Você não está alocando espaço para a string. Você pode ter até 99 index, pelo que me parece, mas não aloca em matriz. De qualquer forma, você botou a tag C++, então, deveria usar containers e std::string.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas! Então, na verdade estou estudando um programinha C++ pronto, acabei seguindo os padrões dele que parecem ser em C... Enfim, estava meio perdido mesmo! Toda pesquisa que fazia na net referente a C++ me retornavam esses métodos e essa forma aí de fazer o código... hehehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é preciso usar matriz bi-dimensional para esse caso. É muito mais fácil de entender (e mais natural) usar-se uma vetor de estruturas. Muito menos necessário ainda é o uso de uma matriz-bidimensional de ponteiros!! Isso dá nó na cabeça de qualquer um.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Pessoa
{
  char nome[20];
  char email[60];
} Pessoa;

int main(void)
{
  char str[256];
  Pessoa pessoas[100];
  int i, nPessoas = 0;

  FILE* fp = fopen("emails.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    printf("* erro na abertura do arquivo\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("*\n");

  while (nPessoas < 100)
  {
    if (fgets((char*)str, 255, fp) == NULL)
    {
      printf("* fim de arquivo\n");
      break;
    }

    if (sscanf(str, "%19s%59s", pessoas[nPessoas].nome, pessoas[nPessoas].email) != 2)
    {
      printf("* erro, linha mal formatada\n");
      printf("*\n");
      continue;
    }

    nPessoas++;
  }

  printf("*\n");
  printf("* numero de pessoas: %d\n", nPessoas);
  printf("*\n");

  for (i = 0; i < nPessoas; i++)
  {
    printf("* pessoa %d\n", i);
    printf("*   nome:[%s]\n", pessoas[i].nome);
    printf("*   email:[%s]\n", pessoas[i].email);
  }

  printf("*\n");
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! Vou estudar certinho seu código para implementá-lo! Agradeço pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 0):

Fiquei na duvida se você está utilizando C ou C++, por que a pergunta fala C++ e o código está em C.

Eu fiz aqui um exemplo de como ler um arquivo utilizando C++.

Supondo que seu arquivo Emails.txt esteja da seguinte forma:

```
nome1 email1@email.com
nome2 email2@email.com
nome3 email3@email.com
nome4 email4@email.com
nome5 email5@email.com
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() {
  std::string filename = "Emails.txt";

  // Abre o arquivo.
  std::ifstream infile(filename);

  std::map<std::string, std::string> lines;

  if(infile.is_open()){
    std::string name, email;

    // Ler o arquivo linha por linha.
    while(infile >> name >> email) {
      lines[name] = email;
    }
  }else{
    std::cerr << "Não foi possível abrir o seguinte arquivo: " << filename << std::endl;
  }

  // Fecha o arquivo.
  infile.close();

  // Exibe a lista.
  for(auto const& line : lines) {
    std::cout << line.first << " " << line.second << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Vinicius! Então, na verdade estou estudando um programinha C++ pronto, acabei seguindo os padrões dele que parecem ser em C... Enfim, estava meio perdido mesmo! Vou estudar certinho seu código para entender e implementá-lo! Obrigado!